# Insert vertical bar between each character of a string in R

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

How would I be able to insert a vertical bar in between every character of a string in R? For example, say I have a string "ABC123". How could I obtain the output to be "A|B|C|1|2|3"? If anyone could vectorize this idea for a vector of character strings, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `regex`

```
gsub("(?<=.)(?=.)", "|", "ABC123", perl = TRUE)
#[1] "A|B|C|1|2|3"
```

Or with more than one string

```
mystrings <- c("ABC123", "PASDP")
gsub("(?<=.)(?=.)", "|", mystrings, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "A|B|C|1|2|3" "P|A|S|D|P"
```

Comment: Does anyone recommend any specific resources for string manipulation in R? I would consider myself a pretty strong R programmer, but I still struggle with basic string manipulations like this.

Answer (score 2):

First, separate into individual characters and then collapse

```
paste(unlist(strsplit("ABC123", "")), collapse = "|")
#[1] "A|B|C|1|2|3"
```

For vector of strings, use `sapply` to loop through them

```
mystrings = c("ABC123", "PASDP")
sapply(strsplit(mystrings, ""), paste, collapse = "|")
#[1] "A|B|C|1|2|3" "P|A|S|D|P"
```

Comment: I came up with `paste0( strsplit("ABC123", "")[[1]], collapse="|")`, but that's essentially the same.